# Algorithm help: Calculate binary possibilities whilst ignoring zero bits

Tags: algorithm, binary

I'm trying to develop an algorithm to test if binary number A is a "sub-number" of binary number B.

A is a sub-number of B if it can be created using only the "1" bits from B.

For example:

If B = Decimal 5 = Binary 101
Then A = {100,001,101} because they use only the bits which were active in B.

If B = Decimal 8 = Binary 1000
Then A = {1000}

If B = Decimal 7 = Binary 1110
Then A = {1000,0100,0010,1100,0110,1010,1110}

n(A) = (2^(number of active bits))-1

How can I develop a test for whether a decimal number x is in the set A for decimal number B? E.g. IsSubNumber(A,B)

IsSubNumber(1,7) = true
IsSubNumber(2,8) = false

Does this make sense?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A` is a subnumber of `B` if bitwise-and between `A` and `B` is equal to `A`.

Example: `1000 & 1110 = 1000`, `1010 & 1110 = 1010`, `101 & 101 = 101`...

In java:

```
boolean isSubNumber(int a, int b) {
    return (a&b) == a;
}
```

Comment: Genius, and simple. Thank you. I knew there had to be a way!

Comment: You need to add parenthesis around a&b because this will cause a compilation error due to == having higher precedence.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, if bit i in A is a 1, then it also must be 1 in B. So simply loop over A, if the current bit is a 1, then check the corresponding bit in B, if it's not a 1, then output false, otherwise keep on testing the next bit in A until you find a mismatch, or you run out of bits.